# rbind the list returned from a function without loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, rbind

In R, for a function whose input is one variable and output is a list, how can I apply the function to a list of inputs and combine the output lists into one data frame or matrix?

For example:

```
fun = function(x){
    list = c(x, x+1, x+2)
    return(list)
}
```

Now I'd like to apply fun() to a list, say

```
list = c(1,11,21)
```

The result should be

```
1,2,3
11,12,13
21,22,23
```

I know do.call and loop will do it. But is there a better way of doing it, perhaps without looping? The actual function is too big and too slow, I would rather not looping it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` :

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list, fun))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]   11   12   13
#[3,]   21   22   23
```

Instead of numeric vector if you return a named list, you can use `map.*` functions from `purrr`.

```
fun = function(x){
  list = list(a = x, b = x+1, c = x+2)
  return(list)
}

purrr::map_df(list, fun)
#OR
#purrr::map_dfr(list, fun)

#     a     b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3
#2    11    12    13
#3    21    22    23
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a matrix, `sapply` is probably sufficient.

```
lst <- c(1,11,21)  ## don't use `list` since it is a function name!

t(sapply(lst, fun))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]   11   12   13
# [3,]   21   22   23
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some base R solutions:

- An easy option is using `Vectorize` + `t`, i.e.,

```
t(Vectorize(fun)(list))
```

such that

```
> t(Vectorize(fun)(list))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]   11   12   13
[3,]   21   22   23
```

- Another way is using `replicate` (considering the additive property of your function `fun`), i.e.,

```
t(replicate(length(list),fun(0)))+list
```

such that

```
> t(replicate(length(list),fun(0)))+list
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]   11   12   13
[3,]   21   22   23
```

Comment: Syntax `Vectorize(fun)(lst)` strikes me, how does that work? `"Vectorize(fun)"` seems to be the new function name?

Comment: @jay.sf well...I have no idea how to explain it in details... `fun` is a object name being vectorized, which is the equivalent to `fun <- Vectorize(function (x) ...) `